# MS Graph API call lists works but not pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I make two API calls

1. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{my-site_id}/lists](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bmy-site_id%7D/lists)
2. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{my-site_id}/pages/microsoft.graph.sitePage](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bmy-site_id%7D/pages/microsoft.graph.sitePage)

First one returns data. 2nd one returns "BadRequest","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'pages'

Any idea why this 2nd API call fails

If successful, this method returns a 200 and a list of sitePage object in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

[Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta) are still in preview which means it works only for beta endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{my-site_id}/pages/microsoft.graph.sitePage
```

Checking the [roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Microsoft%20Graph) and it should be generally available during this month (9/2023)